# Building an expert system/decision based in PHP

Tags: php, decision-tree, expert-system

The problem I am trying to solve is I have 16 different animals and I need to write a PHP script that asks the user 4 yes/no questions and each question narrows down the available animals until eventually the answer is displayed. This means that the next question will depend on what the user answered in the previous question. Do you have any idea how I can do this without using loads of if else statements.

Below is what I have done so far, not finished but if I carry on using if statements I will just end up with too much, there must be a better way to do it. Someone suggested to me using arrays within arrays, but that doesn't help me. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(2592000);
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Creature Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Creature Guessing Game</h1>
<p> Welcome to the creature guessing game! </p>
<p>Click the button 

below to start or restart the game </p>

<form method="post" action="Creatures.php">
<input type='submit' name='start' value='Start Game' />
</form>
 <?php
//If form not submitted, display form.
if (!isset($_POST['start'])){
?>
<?php
} //If form is submitted, process input

else{ //Question 1
echo "<p>Does the creature live mainly on the land?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes1' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no1' value='No' />
</form>";
}
if ($_POST['yes1']){ //Q1 - Yes
echo "<p>Does the creature have wings?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes2' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no2' value='No' />
</form>";
}
elseif($_POST['no1']){ //Q1 - No
echo "<p>Does the creature live in the water?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes3' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no3' value='No' />
</form>";
}
if ($_POST['yes2']){ //Q1 - Yes and Q2 - Yes
echo "<p>Can the creature fly?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes4' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no4' value='No' />
</form>";
}
elseif($_POST['no2']){ //Q1 - Yes and Q2 - No
echo "<p>Is the creature an insect?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes5' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no5' value='No' />
</form>";
}
if ($_POST['yes3']){ //Q1 - No and Q2 - Yes
echo "<p>Is the creature a reptile?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes6' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no6' value='No' />
</form>";
}
if ($_POST['no3']){ //Q1 - No and Q2 - No
echo "<p>Does the creature have feathers?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes7' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no7' value='No' />
</form>";
}
if ($_POST['yes4']){ //Q1 - Yes and Q2 - Yes and Q3 - Yes
echo "<p>Is the creature your thinking of white?</p>";
echo "<form method='post' action='Creatures.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes8' value='Yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no8' value='No' />
</form>";
}
if ($_POST['yes8']){ //Answer 1: Q1 - Yes and Q2 - Yes and Q3 - Yes and Q4 - Yes 
echo "<p>Its a goose!</p>";
}
if ($_POST['no8']){ //Answer 2: Q1 - Yes and Q2 - Yes and Q3 - Yes and Q4 - No
echo "<p>Its a hawk!</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a php developer over here but what you need to do is have an `Animal` class or object that has a set of properties.  These properties should be `Boolean` (true/false) values that map directly back to the questions you are asking about.  These `Animal` objects should be put into a `Collection` (a `List` or a `Set`).  After each question is processed invoke a function that removes all animals whose boolean property do not match the value supplied by the user.  For instance:

```
Animal cat = new Animal();  
cat.canWalkOnLand = true;  

userDoesAnimalWalkOnLand = false;  
for(Animal in AnimalCollection)  
{  
    if(Animal.canWalkOnLand != userDoesAnimalWalkOnLand)  
    {  
       AnimalCollection.remove(Animal);
    }  
}
```

This should be more than enough to get you started.  (Verbose variable names to help you understand)

Comment: I will try this and see how I get on, might also look into using arrays and a switch statement as suggested by the other guy.

Comment: this way is the best way to go, allows for dynamic expansion (adding more animals) or having multiple animals be the 'correct' answer. This approach is the most dynamic and therefore, in my opinion, the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of questions, and use a switch statement and a small function that repeats the same crap over and over again that just accepts your question as a parameter - it would clean up your code a lot.

As far as expanding this game between just the two animals you have listed, Woot4Moo's suggestion would be highly recommended in addition to mine.

Comment: I have added an array of questions and have made a function to repeat the echo "<form>..." stuff and am using a switch statement with $_POST as the variable but its not working?